# Java, splitting string into array

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am trying to split a string into string array. And I have stumbled to something strange to me. I don't understand why it works like this.

```
   String one, two;
    
    one = "";
    two = ":";
    
    
    String[] devided1 = one.trim().split(":");
    String[] devided2 = two.trim().split(":");
    
    System.out.println("size: "+ devided1.length);
    System.out.println("size: "+ devided2.length);
```

I get output:

```
   size: 1
   size: 0
```

Why is empty string giving me size of one, but string that only has the delimiter gives my array size of 0?
I saw more confusing things like: that size of "::" is 0, but size of ": :" is 2, not 3.
Can someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [doc comment in source code](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) or [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)) for `public String[] split(String regex, int limit)` method.

**Case 1:**

```
String one = "";
String[] devided1 = one.trim().split(":");
```

The resulting array will have 1 element = original string `String[1] [""]`, because expresion `":"` was not match any part of the input string.

According to documentation:

> If the
> * expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array
> * has just one element, namely this string.

**Case 2:**

```
String two = ":";
String[] devided2 = two.trim().split(":");
```

The `split(":")` has default `limit = 0`. It means that from the resulting array **trailing empty strings** will be removed. So method splits `":"` string to array with two empty strings and then remove them and as result we get empty array.

According to documentation:

> If limit is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as
> possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings
> will be discarded.

**Case 3:**

```
String two = ":";
String[] devided2 = two.trim().split(":", -1);
```

We will get an array with two empty strings.

According to documentation:

> If limit is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many
> times as possible and the array can have any length

**Case 4:**

```
String two = "::";
String[] devided2 = two.trim().split(":");
```

We will get empty array. It is the same like **Case 2**.

**Case 5:**

```
String one = ": :";
String[] devided1 = one.trim().split(":");
```

The method will split string to three array elements `["", " ", ""]` and then remove empty strings from the end of array, because `limit = 0`. We will get `String[2] ["", " "]`.

According to documentation:

> If limit is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as
> possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings
> will be discarded.

Answer (score -1):

This link is helpful:

https://konigsberg.blogspot.com/2009/11/final-thoughts-java-puzzler-splitting.html

Basically, it is for perl compatibility.

You can use `split(":", -1)` here if you don't want that behavior.

Otherwise, `split(":")` defaults to `split(":", 0)`, and the difference is:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)

- If the limit is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, **and trailing empty strings will be discarded.**
- If the limit is negative then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.

In case of `":"` being splitted, it would result in `{"" , ""}`, but empty traling spaces will be discarded, so it will return an empty array.